# How to show a Text view after amount of seconds in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, time, swiftui, timer

I would like to show a Text saying "Keep the device vertical to continue" when the user keeps the device up for too long (around 3-4 seconds). What can I do? Any suggestions appreciated...

This is how the code looks like:

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreMotion

struct ContentView: View {

    let motionManager = CMMotionManager()
    let queue = OperationQueue()
    @State private var roll = Double.zero
    
    let timer = Timer.publish(every: 1, tolerance: 0.5, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()
    @State private var timeRemaining = 30

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("You have \(timeRemaining) seconds left")
                .onReceive(timer) { _ in
                    if timeRemaining > 0 {
                        timeRemaining -= 1
                    }
                }
            if roll < 1 {
            //Show "HIGH" if the user raises head
                Text("HIGH")
            } else if roll > 2.1 {
            //Show "LOW" if user lowers head
                Text("LOW")
            } else {
            //Otherwise show another Text view
                Text("Move the device!")
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            //Detect device motion
            self.motionManager.startDeviceMotionUpdates(to: self.queue) { (data: CMDeviceMotion?, error: Error?) in
                guard let data = data else {
                    print("Error: \(error!)")
                    return
                }
                let attitude: CMAttitude = data.attitude
                
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.roll = attitude.roll
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

## Approach

- I feel it is best not to use a timer to show the warning since the roll values keep coming continuously.
- So I check for 30 consecutive incorrect values and then show warning

## SwiftUI View properties

- Don't declare `let motionManager = CMMotionManager()` inside the view, as the view might be recreated. Imagine this is a subview inside another view and the parent view's state changes, then the subview would get recreated and hence the models would be recreated.(SwiftUI forces you to separate model and view code)
- Also it is nice separate the model code from the view

## Code

### MotionService

```
import Foundation
import CoreMotion
import Combine

class MotionService: ObservableObject {
    @Published var roll = Double.zero
    @Published var timeRemaining = 15
    @Published var deviceWarning = false
    private let motionManager = CMMotionManager()
    private let startDate = Date()
    private let monitorTimer = Timer.publish(every: 1, tolerance: 0.5, on: .main, in: .default).autoconnect()
    private var cancellable: AnyCancellable?
    private var consecutiveLowRollValues = [Double]()
    
    init() {
        cancellable = monitorTimer.sink { [weak self] firedDate in
            self?.timerFired(at: firedDate)
        }
        startMotionUpdates()
    }
    
    private func timerFired(at firedDate: Date) {
        
        if timeRemaining - 1 <= 0 {
            cancellable?.cancel()
            motionManager.stopDeviceMotionUpdates()
            timeRemaining = 0
        } else {
            timeRemaining -= 1
        }
    }
    
    private func startMotionUpdates() {
        //OperationQueue.main is used so values will be received in the main queue
        motionManager.startDeviceMotionUpdates(to: .main) { [weak self] data, error in
            
            if let error = error {
                print(error)
                return
            }
            
            guard let data = data else {
                return
            }
            
            self?.roll = data.attitude.roll
                        
            if data.attitude.roll < 1 {
                self?.consecutiveLowRollValues.append(data.attitude.roll)
                
                if self?.consecutiveLowRollValues.count ?? 0 > 30 {
                    self?.deviceWarning = true
                }
            } else {
                self?.consecutiveLowRollValues = []
                self?.deviceWarning = false
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### ContentView

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @StateObject private var motionService = MotionService()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(timeRemainingText)
            
            if motionService.deviceWarning  {
                Text("Keep the device vertical to continue")
            } else if motionService.roll < 1 {
                //Show "HIGH" if the user raises head
                Text("HIGH")
            } else if motionService.roll > 2.1 {
                //Show "LOW" if user lowers head
                Text("LOW")
            } else {
                //Otherwise show another Text view
                Text("Move the device!")
            }
        }
    }
    
    private var timeRemainingText: String {
        if motionService.timeRemaining > 0 {
            return "You have \(motionService.timeRemaining) seconds left"
        } else {
            return "Complete"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Neither the first nor the second solution work, first one: I cannot apply dispatch queue because i have to add a Text view after 3 seconds, and i'm in a VStack, second one: should I apply .task after my Text view? why you applied it after the VStack? Also, what do you mean with roll = 3 ? If you look at my code you can see that roll is an attitude property of CMDeviceMotion, this value is used to detect device motion

Comment: @Fabez updated the answer and explained my approach