# How can I pass Binding<CMMotionManager> in SwiftUI preview?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, core-motion, cmmotionmanager

I passed the motionManager of my app from ContentView to SecondView and it works fine, but i don't know how to pass it in the preview of my SecondView, it wants argument type `Binding<CMMotionManager>`

### ContentView

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreMotion

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var motionManager = CMMotionManager()
    let queue = OperationQueue()
    @State private var roll = Double.zero
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                
                Text("Roll is: \(roll)")
                    .font(.largeTitle)
                
                NavigationLink {
                    SecondView(motionManager: $motionManager)
                } label: {
                    Text("Change View")
                }
            }
            .onAppear {
                //Detect device motion
                self.motionManager.startDeviceMotionUpdates(to: self.queue) { (data: CMDeviceMotion?, error: Error?) in
                    guard let data = data else {
                        print("Error: \(error!)")
                        return
                    }
                    let attitude: CMAttitude = data.attitude
                    
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.roll = attitude.roll
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### SecondView

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreMotion

struct SecondView: View {
    @Binding var motionManager: CMMotionManager
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, World!")
    }
}

struct SecondView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        SecondView(motionManager: Binding<CMMotionManager>) <-- //What should i pass here??
    }
}
```

Comment: Pass an instance of it.

Comment: I think this would make a lot more sense as a [custom environment value](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/environmentvalues) than a binding.

Comment: @cora In the apple developer documentation there's clearly stated: "Create only one CMMotionManager object for your app. Multiple instances of this class can affect the rate at which data is received"

Comment: @Coder-256 Can you show me the code? Maybe with an answer instead of a comment, i'd mark it as accepted

Comment: It's fine for a preview.

Comment: @cora What do you think about making motionManager a static let instead of State private var and then call it in the SecondView, like this ContentView.motionManager?

Comment: You need to rework the whole thing. @State does not work with classes. You need to make another class that will manage the motion manager, make it ObservableObject so you can redraw the view when motion manager's values change.

Comment: Use a `@StateObject`, refer to the solution in https://stackoverflow.com/a/73215773

Comment: you should have `@StateObject var motionManager = CMMotionManager()` in `ContentView` and
 in `SecondView`, have `@ObservedObject var motionManager: CMMotionManager`.

 In the `SecondView_Previews`, just use `SecondView(motionManager: CMMotionManager())`.  This is assuming you have declared `class CMMotionManager: ObservableObject`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need State/Binding for `CMMotionManager`, because it is a reference-typed and, as you mentioned yourself, will be single object.

So just use it by-ref in regular properties

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    private var motionManager = CMMotionManager()   // << here !!
//...
}

struct SecondView: View {
    let motionManager: CMMotionManager   // << here !!
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, World!")
    }
}

struct SecondView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        SecondView(motionManager: CMMotionManager())    // << here !!
    }
}
```

Comment: If second view gets recreated (the parent view state could change) it would create a new instance of motion manager

Comment: No, it is not - same reference of parent `motionManager` will be injected

Comment: Got it, thanks, just got to be careful that the App doesn't have a state object whose state changes, then content view would be recreated.

Comment: @Asperi same thing for the NavigationLink? In ContentView will be: SecondView(motionManager: CMMotionManager()), right?